# How to flatten a tensor with placeholder which is not in the first dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to flatten a tensor from shape [2, None, 7, 7, 256] to [2, None, 49, 256] and the operation is the same as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tensor = tf.keras.backend.placeholder(shape=[2, None, 7, 7, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
reshaped_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, ((tensor.shape[:2]) + (49, 256)))
```

And then I encountered with an error:

> ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (2, None, 49, 256)

How to solve this problem and make the reshape operation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tensor = tf.keras.backend.placeholder([2, None, 7, 7, 256], dtype=tf.float32)
reshaped_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, [2, -1, 49, 256])
```

Then this works for me.